# What's the pronunciation of か in ですか?

Tags: particles, pronunciation, particle-か

Basically, か , its pronunciation is 'ka'. But I hear 'ga', が , in this expression which is in the end of a question. So which one should we choose here? And when do we choose 'ka', when 'ga'?

Comment: Related: [What the difference between using か and が for a question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33078/what-the-difference-between-using-%E3%81%8B-and-%E3%81%8C-for-a-question)

Comment: I think your question is probably really about something called "aspiration".  Most likely, you're hearing /k/ as /g/.  What languages do you speak natively?

Comment: Well, it's true for me to mix them up. I am unsure whether the difference between them is the same as that in Chinese, my native language:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading a written sentence, the reading is as written: か is read ka; が is read ga.

As for choosing which one to use:

か is an interrogative particle and marks the sentence as a regular question.

ですが is the sentence connecting particle が with the meaning of "but" (sometimes also has introductory meaning) In this case, if nothing is said afterwards, there is omitted sentence that the listener should be able to guess based on context.

Common usage is to soften a request or a statement. Examples (that would work in *some* contexts):

~ I would have a question, but... (don't want to bother you, would it still be alright to ask?) = you would like to ask something, but want to be polite and not push the listener into answering, so you just suggest that you have a question so the listener can react on their own volition if they want to answer (at least this is how the situation is presented)

~ I think we should do it, but... (maybe you think otherwise, I may be wrong).

The parts in brackets may or may not have been said out loud.

Comment: Haha, thanks for your answer. In fact, I'm just a very beginner. So I don't konw too many sentences for now. The simplest one that made me confused: 小野さんですか - Here, we should pronouncer 'ka' or 'ga' ?

Comment: The sentence ends with か (and not が), so 'ka'. Maybe some Japanese (depending on the person or maybe region) can pronounce it in the way that is closer to 'ga', just guessing here, but as for basics it would be 'ka'